# How to Call rest end points external from Spring-Integration

Tags: java, rest, spring-integration

I am trying to connect external end points from my Spring-Integration project
Here is my structure

IntegrationConfig.java

```
package com.demo.integration.config;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.demo.integration.bean.Program;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.json.JsonToObjectTransformer;
import org.springframework.integration.json.ObjectToJsonTransformer;
import org.springframework.integration.support.json.Jackson2JsonObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class IntegrationConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel receiveChannel(){
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel replyChannel(){
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "integration.program.gateway.channel", outputChannel = "integration.program.objectToJson.channel")
    public ObjectToJsonTransformer objectToJsonTransformer(){
        return new ObjectToJsonTransformer(getMapper());
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonObjectMapper getMapper(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(mapper);
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "integration.program.jsonToObject.channel", outputChannel = "integration.program.jsonToObject.fromTransformer.channel")
    public JsonToObjectTransformer jsonToObjectTransformer(){
        return new JsonToObjectTransformer(Program.class);
    }
}
```

ProgramService.java

```
package com.demo.integration.service;

import com.demo.integration.bean.Program;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ProgramService {
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "integration.program.objectToJson.channel", outputChannel = "integration.program.jsonToObject.channel")
    public Message<?> receiveMessage(Message<?> message){
        System.out.println("###############");
        System.out.println(message);
        System.out.println("###############");
        System.out.println("Object To JSON : "+message.getPayload());
        //Message<String> newMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getPayload() + "Modified").build();
        return message;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "integration.program.jsonToObject.fromTransformer.channel")
    public void processJsonToObject(Message<?> message){
        MessageChannel replyChannel = (MessageChannel) message.getHeaders().getReplyChannel();
        MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message);
        System.out.println("JSON To Object : "+message.getPayload());
        Program program = (Program)message.getPayload();
        Message<String> newMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(program.toString() + "Modified").build();
        replyChannel.send(newMessage);
    }
}
```

Program.java

```
package com.demo.integration.bean;


import java.io.Serializable;

public class Program implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String code;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Program{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", code='" + code + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

IntegrationController.java

```
package com.demo.integration.controller;

import com.demo.integration.bean.Program;
import com.demo.integration.service.IntegrationGateway;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/integration")
public class IntegrationRestController {

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationGateway gateway;

    @GetMapping(value = "{name}")
    public String test(
            @PathVariable(value = "name") String name) {
        return gateway.sendMessage(name);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processProgram(@RequestBody Program program) {
        return gateway.processProgram(program);
    }
}
```

Which is the better place to write Rest end point connection call ?
And is it feasible to use RestTemplate in Spring-Integration or any other interface type is available, since here I just need to initiate a call grab the response and send it back to another channel.

Answer (score 1):

RestTemplate is a little old and about to be deprecated i recommed using feignclient or webclient

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html

like:

```
@FeignClient(name = "segmentGroupClient", url = "${cdp.segment-group-base-url}")
public interface SegmentGroupClient {

    @PostMapping(value = "/segment-group",consumes = "application/json")
    ResponseEntity<SegmentGroupResponse> handle(@RequestBody SegmentGroupRequest request);
}
```

and in your apllication.properties:

```
cdp.segment-group-base-url=http://url:port
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I also read on various blogs regarding this. I will try with this and reply you soon. :)

Answer (score 0):

You show too much custom code and neither of it some how points us where you'd like to make a REST call. Anyway Spring Integration has an HTTP and WebFlux modules to let you to have endpoints in your flow for calling the REST service on the other side and wait for response which is going to be a reply message payload for next channel in your flow.

See more in docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/http.html#http

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/webflux.html#webflux

Comment: Hey @Artem sorry for providing too much data, I just wanted to make REST call from my Service layer. thanks for your advice. I appreciate for your time. :)